# How to escape spaces in windows cmd?

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg

Solved, look at Edit2.

I'd like to make a `.bat` file that will call this command:

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie=loud.mp4:s=dv+da[vid][aud];[aud]asplit[aud][out1];[aud]showcqt=1280x720:volume=30:volume2=30,format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.8[out_v];[vid][out_v]overlay[out0]"
```

I'm too lazy to type this every time. I need to replace `loud.mp4` from the line above to a new file.

```
cqt "System Shock Soundtrack - 00 - Intro-6CalFsdE4tA.mp4"
```

I don't understand how single and double quotes work, and how to escape spaces in file paths.

Edit1: I'm trying this:

```
set arg1=%1

ffplay -f lavfi "movie='%arg1%':s=dv+da[vid][aud];[aud]asplit[aud][out1];[aud]showcqt=1280x720:volume=30:volume2=30,format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.8[out_v];[vid][out_v]overlay[out0]"
```

and call it like that:

```
cqt "System Shock Soundtrack - 00 - Intro-6CalFsdE4tA.mp4"
```

but it results in:

```
Argument 'Shock' provided as input filename, but 'movie='System' was already specified.
```

The command that really got executed is this. Notice the `movie='"the movie file name.mp4"'`

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie='"System Shock Soundtrack - 00 - Intro-6CalFsdE4tA.mp4"':s=dv+da[vid][aud];[aud]asplit[aud][out1];[aud]showcqt=1280x720:volume=30:volume2=30,format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.8[out_v];[vid][out_v]overlay[out0]"
```

Edit2: This worked, the `amovie='%~1'`

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie='%~1'[aud];[aud]asplit[aud][out1];[aud]showcqt=1280x720:volume=30:volume2=30[out0]"
```

and calling as:

```
cqta "System Shock Soundtrack - 00 - Intro-6CalFsdE4tA.webm"
```

Comment: Encose the filename+path in single quotes. 'loud.mp4'

Comment: @Mulvya this worked as a stand alone command, need to write a `.bat` file for it now. Added `Edit1` in the post.

Comment: Try `movie='%~1'`

Comment: @Mulvya It worked, thank you.